# specify backward compatibility depth of migrations in apps or projects (django)

Tags: django, django-migrations

Often when one develops django applications, models change and hence migrations are added. IMHO a good practice is to make new code intended for a newer database schema to also be compatible with the older schema, possibly by not showing new functionality.

For example, if you add a function of including a bounding box for a profile photo, this feature is not there if the appropriate table doesn't have the fields for this bounding box. Such graceful degradation can keep a website running, even though not all migrations were executed yet.

This removes some stress during updating live deployments. Distributed web nodes can be updated one at a time, and the migration is done at the end.

Nevertheless, graceful degradation can only go so far, at some point the burden of endless backward comparability is too much a drain on development resources. System administrators, however, can not be expected to be aware of how large this migration code gap can be and verbal communication can easily get noisy. And after a week a developer might have forgotten how migration backward compatible some release is.

This makes me wonder, can an app or a project specify with which migrations it is compatible?

If not, then what is a good update order of *n* web nodes and one database?

Such specification would allow updates to warn about whether or not the database is compatible and vice versa possibly also whether there are outdated web nodes when migrating a database.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that make a migration not compatible with old versions of the code:

- Adding a `NOT NULL` column
- Dropping a column (while it is still used in the old version)
- Renaming a column
- Altering a column (e.g. changing the type)
- Renaming a table

There is a project called [migration-linter](https://github.com/3YOURMIND/django-migration-linter) that can help detecting those backward incompatible migrations in an automated way.

Hope that helps.